# Firebase - optimizing read / write

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider a chat like implementation where clients write using a transaction on the head and read using on('child_added') listener.

When a client writes he will also get a read of the same version he sent which means a redundant transfer of that version from the database. In the case of only one connected client typing for example, all responses to the listener will be redundant.

I tried to optimize this by turning off the listener before writing and turning it on again when writing ended with a startAt(new head). This way I don't get the redundant read of the location that was sent.

This all works fine but I now don't know if the cost of removing and adding the listener may be high as well ? what is the best strategy here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase automatically optimizes it for you. This is pretty much the standard use case; it's what Firebase was designed for. The best strategy is to leave the listener on. Let Firebase do its thing.